# Rotation function in Quaternions

Tags: graphics, quaternions

Book "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphcis(Third Edition)"
Chapter 4 Transform  4.6 Quaterions
it mentions below

"Extending the function φ to a mapping from H onto itself by requiring that
φ(s + v) = s + φ(v) allows us to rewrite Equation"
[image: Rotations with Quaternions]

HERE , i don't know why   "φ(s + v) = s + φ(v)" is requirement when the rotation function extending to H  ?

anyone could show me some idea or documents to explain it ??

Thanks advance !

Answer (score 0):

This is because the author want to characterize H as a "split" field of scalar and vector in R^3. He denote scalar with letter "s" and vector with letter "v". So members of H have the "split" form s + v. Note the + here is similar to complex numbers sum in the sense that what you really have is a pair (s, v) of elements from different fields.

Since the function φ has been defined on vectors so far, it can be applied only to v. So if you want to apply φ to members of H you need the definition φ(s + v) = s + φ(v). This is similar to the concept of overloading a function in C++ so you have two versions of the function with the same name but they act differently depending on the argument.